# List freely available datasets in AWS Marketplace using an API or Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-marketplace, aws-data-exchange

I have a situation where I need to list all the open data sets available in AWS Marketplace.

How can I get the list and dataset details available without any subscription needed either by using AWS data-exchange API or by any other program - maybe using python.

This is the code I used but it was giving empty set may be because I didn't subscribe to any data:

```py
import boto3

# Set up AWS credentials and region 
access_key = '***********************' 
secret_key = '****************' 
region = 'us-east-1' 

# Create an AWS Data Exchange client object 
client = boto3.client('dataexchange', region_name=region, aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key) 

# List available data sets 
response = client.list_data_sets() 

# Print the data set names 
for dataset in response['DataSets']: 
  print(dataset['Name'])
```

It is showing an empty result, maybe because it lists only subscribed data?

Comment: import boto3

    # Set up AWS credentials and region
    access_key = '***********************'
    secret_key = '****************'
    region = 'us-east-1'

# Create an AWS Data Exchange client object
    client = boto3.client('dataexchange', region_name=region, aws_access_key_id=access_key,       aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)

# List available data sets
    response = client.list_data_sets()

# Print the data set names
    for dataset in response['DataSets']:
    print(dataset['Name'])

Comment: this is the code i used but it was giving empty set may be because i  didnt subscribed for any data.

Comment: Listings are available at [Registry of Open Data on AWS](https://registry.opendata.aws/) and [Open Data on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/opendata/?wwps-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.sortDate&wwps-cards.sort-order=desc), but I don't know whether those lists are accessible via API.

Comment: is there a way to list subscribed data sets using postman